# recursively (or non-recursively) iterating through python array and get the elements

Tags: python, arrays

I have a python array data-structure like [[v], [v]] that v is an array of size 2 or another [[v],[v]] data type. you can see the real data below:

```
ex1:

list: [[[1, '1.0.1'], [1, '2.0.1']], [1, '3.0.11']]

ex2:

list: [[[[1, '1.0.1'], [1, '2.0.1']], [1, '3.0.11']], [1, '4.0.11']]
```

now my problem is that I should get elements from left to right first [1, '1.0.1'] then [1, '2.0.1'] and so on. and note that the size of array vary.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have this data structure, and why do you need to iterate over it in this way? It's possible, and not too difficult, but the best solution may be to reorganize your data.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a linked list?

Comment: So your expected output is just a flat list containing all the actual values from left-to-right? If not, can you explain what kind of output you want?

Comment: @user2357112 I tried to so some machine learning thing and generate this data-structure based on my calculation right now I should use this data-structure otherwise I should rewrite so many codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to *flatten* the list:

```
def flatten(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    elif not isinstance(lst, list):
        return [lst] 
    else:
        return flatten(lst[0]) + flatten(lst[1:])
```

This will allow you to traverse the list in order:

```
ls1 = [[[[1, '1.0.1'], [1, '2.0.1']], [1, '3.0.11']], [1, '4.0.11']]
flatten(ls1)
=> [1, '1.0.1', 1, '2.0.1', 1, '3.0.11', 1, '4.0.11']
```

Or alternatively, using generators:

```
def flatten(lst):
    if not lst:
        return
    elif not isinstance(lst, list):
        yield lst
    else:
        for e in flatten(lst[0]):
            yield e
        for e in flatten(lst[1:]):
            yield e

list(flatten(ls1))
=> [1, '1.0.1', 1, '2.0.1', 1, '3.0.11', 1, '4.0.11']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an iterator to do what you want:

```
def iterate(xs):
    try:
        if isinstance(xs[1],str):
            yield xs
            return
    except IndexError:
        pass
    for x in xs:
        yield from iterate(x)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list(iterate([[[[1, '1.0.1'], [1, '2.0.1']], [1, '3.0.11']], [1, '4.0.11']]))
[[1, '1.0.1'], [1, '2.0.1'], [1, '3.0.11'], [1, '4.0.11']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably missing something obvious, so I apologize in advance...

But your data structure seems to be a lot more complicated than it needs to be?

Would

```
v = [(1, '1.0.1'), (1, '2.0.1'), (1, '3.0.11')]
v.append((1, '4.0.11'))
print v
```

do what you want?